# How To Dim Read Items In A UWP App List

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, master-detail

I have a [simple Master/Detail app called Daily Bible Reading](http://anti-exe.com/apps/).

One of my TODO items has been to keep track of what you have read by dimming any `ListView` items that have been.

```
<ListView Name="Chapters" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ChapterCollection}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="Chapter_ItemClick">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:ChapterItem">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind date}" Foreground="White"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ChapterReference}" Foreground="White"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

My thinking is that, when each days content loads or you select one of the items, it sets a variable in the user's `RoamingSettings`.  I'm doing a similar thing for setting `FontSize`.

```
public ApplicationDataContainer roamingsettings = ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings;

private void FontSize_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var newfontsize = FontSizeComboBox.SelectedIndex + 10;

    // store the user preferences
    // get the device name
    var deviceinfo = new Windows.Security.ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning.EasClientDeviceInformation();
    var devicename = deviceinfo.FriendlyName;
    // set the preference
    roamingsettings.Values[devicename + "_FontSize"] = newfontsize.ToString();
}
```

If the user did set it, then respect that preference.

```
// set TextBlock FontSize and then change if the user has preferences
private void SetFontSize(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var textblock = (TextBlock)sender;
    // set a default
    textblock.FontSize = 20;

    // load user preferences
    // get the device name
    var deviceinfo = new Windows.Security.ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning.EasClientDeviceInformation();
    var devicename = deviceinfo.FriendlyName;
    // check to see if the preference is there
    if (roamingsettings.Values.ContainsKey(devicename + "_FontSize"))
    {
        var fontsize = Convert.ToInt32(roamingsettings.Values[devicename + "_FontSize"]);
        textblock.FontSize = fontsize;
    }
}
```

I figure that I can do a similar thing for `Foreground` of the item (just change the `Foreground=White` to `Foreground=Grey`, or something).  The issue is that I don't know how to make a change on a per-item basis.  The font change is global, when the app loads.  My items are being loaded from an `ObservableCollection`.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<ChapterItem> ChapterCollection { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        ChapterCollection = new ObservableCollection<ChapterItem>();
    }

    // what to do when the page is navigated to
    protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        await MainPageViewModel.PopulateCollections(ChapterCollection);
    }
}
```

I assume that the answer lies somewhere in the dark realm of converters.  I say it that way as I haven't been able to wrap my head around them.

I will, happily, post `View` and/or `ViewModel` code, if you want.  I'm not sure if it would be of any benefit to the question.

As a secondary point, I may be thinking about all of this the wrong way.  I know enough about programming to, kind of, make things work.  I don't know enough to know if something is a best practice.  I will say that the app's code is much better than it was a couple years ago.  I welcome any general guidance, aside from the specific question.

Comment: it would probably best accomplished with a flag such as `bool HasBeenRead{get;set;}` then using a `VisualState` which would change the background or the font weight.

Comment: `VisualState` seems like a logical option, given that the updates are purely visual.  I'm using `VisualState` for width-based changes.  I'm assuming it would be something along the lines of `<AdaptiveTrigger HasBeenRead="1" />`.

Comment: AdaptiveTrigger is surprisingly not related. its more related to size of screen and orientation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use a converter and you need an extra property in Model to Bind that with the background/opacity of the StackPanel. You need to add this converter resource at page level or at app level

Let's say you have (bool) "HasBeenRead" then:

```
<ListView Name="Chapters" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ChapterCollection}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="Chapter_ItemClick">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:ChapterItem">
        <StackPanel Background="{x:Bind HasBeenRead, Converter={StaticResource CustomColorConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind date}" Foreground="White"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ChapterReference}" Foreground="White"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

```
public sealed class CustomColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value != null && (bool)value)
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }
        else
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: The converter is doing something, but not what I expected.  It did change the background to yellow (yay!).  When I click the chapter, though, it doesn't turn it red.  In Chapter_ItemClick, I have `var selectedchapter = (ChapterItem)e.ClickedItem;` and `selectedchapter.HasBeenRead = true;`.  Is there something else that I need to do?

Comment: Probably then your "ChapterItem" class is not derived from INotifyPropertyChanged Interface      https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx  When you add/delete any item from ObservableCollection then this collection type takes care of notifying the changes, however here, in this case, we are changing just one property of already added item so you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged Interface in ChapterItem class

Comment: My "ChapterItem" class derives from my "Chapter" class (`public class ChapterItem : Chapter {}`).  My "Chapter" class (`public class Chapter {}`) is a type that's included in a parent "RootObject" class that is pulled from an internet API (`public class RootObject { public List<Chapter> chapters { get; set; } }`).  I assume deriving the "Chapter" class from "INotifyPropertyChanged" would make more sense.  Would "RootObject" be even better?  I have master data classes for the API results.  Then, my ViewModel has classes (derived from those master classes) just for the view.

Comment: Trying to add the `INotifyPropertyChanged` code and hitting a snag.  Since "ChapterItem" already derives from "Chapter", I can't add the interface.  I added it to "Chapter" and everything seemed fine.  But my "HasBeenRead" can't access the `NotifyPropertyChanged()` method, because it's in a different class (different file, even).  If I make the method static, then it can't use the interface.  I don't want to start adding ViewModel stuff into the original Model.

Comment: You can always derive a class from many interfaces. So you can public class ChapterItem : Chapter, INotifyPropertyChanged   ... and then implement the interface. You will need HasBeenRead  in ChapterItem

Comment: Ok, so I haven't gotten the "HasBeenRead" stuff working, but I do have the "IsTodaysChapter" converter working.  I'm happy that, at least, one thing that I've been trying to accomplish is a success.  I'm getting a grasp of the concept.  Unfortunately, interfaces are a whole new can of worms.  Hehehe...